# Symfony update from dropdown in column

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, symfony

I am trying to solve an issue in my symfony project. I want the user to select a value from a dropdown in a column (done) and then update the new value in database. The thing is, when I hit the update value, it gets the old value and does not update. Here is the PHP code

```
/**
 * @Route("/pedidoventa/edit/{id}", name="pventa_edit")
 */
public function editpventaAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $Pedido_Venta = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Pedido_Venta')
        ->find($id);


    $Pedido_Venta->setEstado($Pedido_Venta->getEstado());


        //traer los datos

        $estado = ($Pedido_Venta->getEstado());


        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $Pedido_Venta = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Pedido_Venta')->find($id);

        $Pedido_Venta->setEstado($estado);


        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash(
            'notificacion',
            'Estado Editado'
        );

        return $this->redirectToRoute('pventa_list');
    }
```

And here is the HTML table

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h2 class="page-header">Pedidos de Venta</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Fecha - Hora</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for Pedido_Venta in pedidosventa %}
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{Pedido_Venta.id}}</th>
    <td><a href="/pedidoventa/details/{{Pedido_Venta.id}}">{{Pedido_Venta.fecha}}</a></td>
    <td><select>
            <option selected="selected">{{Pedido_Venta.estado}}</option>
            <option>Listo</option>
            <option>Con Demora</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
    <a href="/pedidoventa/edit/{{Pedido_Venta.id}}" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a>
    <a href="/pedidoventa/delete/{{Pedido_Venta.id}}" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <a href="/pedidoventa/create" class="btn btn-primary">Nuevo Pedido de Venta</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: In your controller, why do you get `Pedido_Venta` and set the `estado` value twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending only ID. Look at your HTML, there is not any `<form>` tag, which is waiting for param from your dropdown. Please create form to handle your problem.